# Best plugins for sonarqube for analysisng Java code

Tags: sonarqube

I am Looking for best plugins for sonarqube to analyze Java code. I found sonar-java plugin, cobertura plugin and is there any other plugins that I can use for analyszing java. My criteria is Timeline, Takeout useless code, SIG maintainability,Technical debt, and quality index.I tried to find but SIG plugin is deprecated.

Sonarqube version-5.6.6

Thanks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available plugins include

- [SonarJava](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/java.html)
- [JDepend](https://github.com/willemsrb/sonar-jdepend-plugin)
- [Findbugs](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/findbugs.html)
- [Checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle)

You can check this link for a list of all available plugins
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library

Comment: Thanks Philip. I am wondering about clover as it became an opensource. is t good for code coverage

Comment: I can't say much about Clover as I use Jacoco for code coverage and it is very good

Comment: Thanks @Philip For quality index sonarjava plugin will be fine?

Comment: Yes. It comes with sonarqube. You just have to activate it in the update center Administration > System > Update Center.